# Angular Material 2 Datepicker with dynamic name

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to implement a datepicker component with a dynamic name.

I am developing in an Angular Material 2 based project with Angular 4, and this is my implementation:

```html
<input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="'start' + column.name + 'Picker'" placeholder="Start {{column.label}}" formControlName="start{{column.name}}">
<button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="'start' + column.name + 'Picker'"></button>
<md-datepicker #start{{column.name}}Picker></md-datepicker>
```

where `column.name` changes dynamically in my html page.

In runtime I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._datepicker._registerInput is not a function
```

Do you have any idea about the cause of this error?

**Note:** Replacing `column.name` with a static value in the `mdDatepicker`  and `mdDatepickerToggle` properties solves the problem, but my goal is to run this code with a dynamic value

**Edit:** The replacement of `column.name` with a static value in the `mdDatepicker`  and `mdDatepickerToggle` properties just solves the runtime error. But the datepicker won't be triggered until everything is static, which means even the name `#start{{column.name}}Picker` in the `md-datepicker` has to contain a static value

Comment: Wrap it in `ng-template` and you will no need dynamic template reference name

Comment: If I wrap all my code inside an `ng-template` all the date block disappears. According to [the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax): _If there is no structural directive and you merely wrap some elements in a <ng-template>, those elements disappear_

Comment: Use `ngTemplateOutlet` to display `template`

Comment: It works with `ngTemplateOutlet` but in a static way: The value `dateTemplate` in the `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="dateTemplate"></ng-container>` and that refers to the `ng-template` that contains my previous code has to change dynamically, and again if I use something like `*ngTemplateOutlet="'start' + column.name"` or `*ngTemplateOutlet="start{{column.name}}"` I would have runtime errors

Comment: No, not like this

Comment: Do you have any helpful link that shows the right way to implement it?

Comment: What is wrong with it? https://plnkr.co/edit/JdCQ8tdInwpjK3Awu1Rk?p=preview

Comment: That's perfect, I tried to do it the hard way while the solution is more simple :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe a better solution is to use an index while iterating over the array

```
 <div *ngFor="let column of columns; let i=index">
   <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="i" placeholder="Start {{column.label}}" name="{{column.name}}">
   <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="i"></button>
   <md-datepicker #i></md-datepicker>
 </div>
```

This way you can access each element individually via element ref

Comment: This is the correct answer : works like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I would like to point out [the solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdCQ8tdInwpjK3Awu1Rk?p=preview) proposed by @yurzui in the comments associated to the question, so it would be visible to everyone:

```html
<div *ngFor="let column of columns">
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="startPicker" placeholder="Start {{column.label}}">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="startPicker"></button>
  <md-datepicker #startPicker></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

```
columns = [ 
    {
      label: 'column1',
      name: 'name1'
    },
    {
      label: 'column1',
      name: 'name1'
    },
    {
      label: 'column1',
      name: 'name1'
    }  
]
```

Answer (score -1):

When using dynamic material datepicker in reactive form array, using the index directly clashes with the formGroupName. Using "ii" solved the issue for me.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('myFormArray').controls; let i = index">
 <div [formGroupName]="i">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="myDate" [matDatepicker]="ii" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="ii"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #ii touchUi></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
 </div>
</div>
```