# Angular multi matDatepicker with ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create matDatepickers inside ngFor. I Used like below

```
   <div *ngFor="let interim_payment_date of interim_payment_multi; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="interim_payment_[i]" placeholder="Choose a date" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                [(ngModel)]="interim_payment_datem.date">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="interim_payment_[i]"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker [id]="interim_payment_[i]"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

**And This is My Component**

```
export class PaymentPlanComponent implements OnInit {

interim_payment_multi = [];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

this.interim_payment_multi[0] = { date: null };
this.interim_payment_multi[1] = { date: null };
this.interim_payment_multi[2] = { date: null };
}
```

I get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: interim_payment_datemulti = [];

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka It was typo when I copied here.  same error continues.

Comment: @kemalatila check this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884148/9775003)